# Python Tkinter Listbox not highlighting

Tags: tkinter

When i try clicking on the left listbox, it only highlights in blue the right one. How do i make it highlight both listbox's?

```
from Tkinter import *
root=Tk()
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill=Y )


mylist = Listbox(root, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set )
for line in range(100):
   mylist.insert(END, "This is line number " + str(line))
mylist.pack( side = RIGHT, fill = BOTH )

mylist2 = Listbox(root, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set )
for line in range(100):
   mylist2.insert(END, "This is line number " + str(line))
mylist2.pack( side = RIGHT, fill = BOTH )

def scroll_bar(*args):
    mylist.yview(*args)
    mylist2.yview(*args)
scrollbar.config( command = scroll_bar )
def side_highlight(e):
    select_number= mylist2.curselection() #gets where in listbox is selected
    mylist.selection_set(select_number)

mylist2.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', side_highlight)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `exportselection` argument to `False` when you define your listbox, so that it can have multiple items selected. So your code would look something  like this:

```
from Tkinter import *
root=Tk()
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack( side = RIGHT, fill=Y )


mylist = Listbox(root, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set, exportselection = False)
for line in range(100):
   mylist.insert(END, "This is line number " + str(line))
mylist.pack( side = RIGHT, fill = BOTH )

mylist2 = Listbox(root, yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set, exportselection = False)
for line in range(100):
   mylist2.insert(END, "This is line number " + str(line))
mylist2.pack( side = RIGHT, fill = BOTH)

def scroll_bar(*args):
    mylist.yview(*args)
    mylist2.yview(*args)
scrollbar.config( command = scroll_bar )
def side_highlight(e):
    select_number= mylist2.curselection() #gets where in listbox is selected
    mylist.selection_clear(0, END)      # Needs to clear all previous elements
    mylist.selection_set(select_number)

mylist2.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', side_highlight)

root.mainloop()
```